# Has anyone heard of a JSON schema that generates a Json schema?

Tags: json, linux, jsonschema

I'm looking for a Json Schema that generates a Json schema. that sounds a little confusing but if I can try to simplify it I'm looking for a Json schema that out lines the rules to make a Json schema and outputs them.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the meta-schemas. From `JSONSchema`:

> ## Meta-schemas
>
> The meta-schemas are the schemas which define the JSON Schema and Hyper-> Schema formats.
>
> Core/Validation Meta-Schema:  Used for schemas written for pure validation.
>
> Hyper Meta-Schema:    Used for schemas written for validation and hyper-linking.

Taken from: http://json-schema.org/documentation.html